# Routing path with ServiceStack

Tags: angularjs, servicestack

I'm using AngularJS, I want to do the following routing on ServiceStack-serving-static-html

[image]

Note the **intercept any path** on the screenshot.

Also note I'm not using ServiceStack for REST, I'm using it as pure webserver for serving static contents, e.g. html

Is it possible to do that on ServiceStack?

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this as well.  I've abandoned my attempt to use html5 style urls because of it.  If you find a solution, please post it back here ... I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is node.js code, you haven't shown any C# ServiceStack AppHost code here.

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) by default supports serving of static content via HTTP, although to serve static content from the root directory of your app you should host it at `/`.

You've not mentioned whether you're using hosting ServiceStack via ASP.NET host or as a stand-alone self-hosting HttpListener. If it's the latter you also need to, in VS.NET set your files you want to mark the `Build Action` of your static files as **Content** and set it's `Copy to Output Directory` as **Copy if Newer**.

Comment: Yep, I know it's node.js. Just wanted to know if routing is possible with ServiceStack(serving html). I'm using ServiceStack using stand-alone self-hosting. Aside from routing on client-side with AngularJS, the routing should be supported by server-side too, I'm thinking if routing is possible on ServiceStack serving the html.  Here's where I get the screenshot: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uhZCc0j9RY